# Passing a variable from the archive page to the default template

Tags: get-template-part

I have created an archive page that will display the whole content of list of posts. The individual post content output should be managed from a specialized that I will integrate using the WP built-in get_template_part function. (I assume this is the best way to work).

My challenge is that I do need to get access to some variable which scope has been defined in the archive page. How do I access to them?

Should I make them "global"?

Comment: One thing you could do is globalize the variables is they're static. Another option is to just not use `get_template_part` but instead a conditional to decide whether to use this format or that format.

Comment: What variable? And how is it used in the template-part file markup?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee not sure I can get the bit about the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `get_template_part`. Instead use

```
include( locate_template( 'your-template-part.php' ) );
```

This will make your variables available to the included file without having to use the global keyword.

Comment: So in my archive.pho page, I will add a line like the above and the variable defined in archive will be immediately accessible to the content.php (my single item file). Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct